# Showing that $(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_x\cong \mathbb{C}[x]_x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization

I'd like to understand rigorously why $(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_x\cong \mathbb{C}[x]_x$.

Intuitively, it seems reasonable. However I'd like to know whether the kernel of the map I've constructed for the isomorphism is correct.

We can start with a map $f:\mathbb{C}[x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]_x$ mapping $f(x,y) \mapsto f(x,0)\mapsto f(x,0)/1$. If the kernel of this map is $(xy)$,we get a map $f:\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]_x$.

This gives us an induced map from $(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_x\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]_x$ by the universal property of localization, and it is not hard to show that this is a bijection.

However, is the kernel in fact $(xy)$?

We have $\rm ker f= \{f(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]\mid f(x,0)/1=0/x^n \text{ for some $n$}\}$, and so the kernel consists of elements of the form $x^nf(x,y)$ where $f(x,0)=0$ or $x=0$. Does this imply that the kernel is $(xy)$?

Comment: Here's a different way to approach the problem. Localization commutes with quotients (it's an exact functor), so we can instead start with $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}$ and quotient out by the ideal generated (in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}$) by $(xy)$. But $x$ is a unit in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}$, so...

Comment: Or maybe think about it like this: under the map $f$ you've given $x$ is mapped to a unit (also $x$). So by the universal property of localization, $f$ extends to a map $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_x \to \mathbb{C}[x]_x$.

Comment: @RichardD.James Yes, I've updated my question. I understand that we get such an induced map. However, how can one show it is an isomorphism?

Comment: Hint: have you ever heard of the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: @KReiser The first isomorphism theorem gives us the map out of the quotient. It's already used above if you read my question. I would like to know how to proceed from here. Unless I'm missing some other application of the theorem

Comment: I don't think what you've written is correct. The kernel of the map you've written is $(y)$. Once you localize, since $x$ is a unit in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}$, then $(xy) = (y)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}$. Like I mentioned above, the key is that we can quotient or localize in either order, so it really comes down to showing that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}/(xy) \cong (\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_x$.

Comment: Yes, it gives you a map out of the quotient, but it also tells you something *specific* about the map out of the quotient! It's a certain type of map, one that would be particularly useful to you here.

Comment: @RichardD.James Shouldn't it then be $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_x/(xy)_x$?

Comment: @KReiser Indeed, the map out of the quotient is injective, but this doesn't tell you that the map out of the localization is injective.

Comment: Proving that the map out of the localization is injective is straightforwards and relies on the fact that the map from the quotient is injective. This is where I'm going to get off - you have quite a few hints in the comments (enough to solve the problem, imo) and I think you'd be better served by writing up your attempt with these hints (and putting it in your question if you're not convinced you have a proof) than me posting more hints.

Comment: @ponchan You can use that notation if you like. When ever I write $(r)$ for some element $r \in R$, I mean the ideal generated by $r$ in $R$. When I wrote $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}/(xy)$, I meant the quotient by the ideal generated by $xy$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}$. There is some chance for confusion, but the meaning should be clear: if I'm going to quotient out $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}$ by it, what else could I mean but an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{x}$?

Answer (score 7):

We have a short exact sequence of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$-modules
$$0\rightarrow (xy)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)\rightarrow 0.$$
Then note that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_x$ is a flat $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$-module. In particular, the functor $(-)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}\mathbb{C}[x,y]_x$ is exact, not just right exact. Hence if we tensor the above short exact sequence, we get
$$0\rightarrow (xy)_x\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]_x\rightarrow \left(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)\right)_x\rightarrow 0.$$
Note that the ideal$(xy)_x$ is just the principal ideal $(y)\subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]_x$. Thus rewriting the above exact sequence using this isomorphism, we get
$$0\rightarrow (y)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]_x\rightarrow \left(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)\right)_x\rightarrow 0.$$
However we also have a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow (y)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]\rightarrow 0.$$
And thus after tensoring with $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_x$, we get a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow (y)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]_x\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]_x\rightarrow 0.$$
Since the cokernel is unique up to isomorphism, we see that
$$\left(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)\right)_x\cong \mathbb{C}[x]_x.$$