# visualizing nilpotents

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Trying to work through exercise 5.2.C of [The rising sea foundation of algebraic geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf). Specifically want to show that $(k[x,y] / (y^2, xy))_{x}$ has no nilpotents. This is easy by recognizing that the resulting ring is just the ring of Laurent series. However, the hint directs the reader to show that it is isomorphic to another ring, by considering the geometric picture. I am not quite sure how to do this.

To start, $(k[x,y] / (y^2, xy))$ can be thought of as the axis $y  = 0$ together with $x = 0$. But how do you think about the point $(x)$ which is not a maximal ideal, thus not identified with a point in $k^2$?

Comment: *The rising sea* has a picture of the scheme $\mathrm{Spec}\,k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ (Fig. 4.4). By localizing at $x$, you're throwing away the origin (more precisely, the line $x=0$). Can you see why the resulting space is $\mathrm{Spec}\,k[x]_x$?

Comment: The resulting ring **is not** "just the ring of Laurent series", but is  $k[x] _{x}$, the $k$-algebra of rational functions defined at $0$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769097/showing-that-mathbbcx-y-xy-x-cong-mathbbcx-x)

Comment: Why by localizing at $x$, the line $x = 0$ get thrown away? Would you mind expanding on that point a bit? @ShiveringSoldier

Comment: The prime ideals of $A_f$ correspond to prime ideals of $A$ **not** containing $f$. So in your case, you're throwing away the closed set $V(x)$. Also, see Exercise 3.2.K of *The rising sea* for a detailed example.